# How to edit panorama images taken with landscape mode with different shutter speeds?

Tags: panorama

I want to stitch more than 5 images into panorama. I took all those images using landscape mode which means some images have different shutter speeds therefore exposures. How can I fix exposure of all those images in Lightroom so it would fit to panorama just fine? Any tricks to compare two different images side by side while able to change settings for the other?

Comment: What about the other settings of the camera? Are the pictures taken at same ISO-Setting? Same contrast level? Are there any other settings which are different, or just Shutter speed?

Comment: In Lightroom you can try the Match Total Exposures functionality. [This relevant previous answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/6975/9161) tells a bit about it.

Comment: Check this answer for your next panorama shoot: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12443/how-do-i-create-a-panoramic-picture/12471#12471

Comment: @Vertigo, Same ISO (500), focal length (135mm) and aperture (f/5.6). The only thing differs is shutter speed (between 60 and 125)

Comment: How can I use math to manually calculate the necessary chance for exposure in LR while only shutter speed varies (example 1/60 ; 1/80; 1/100; 1/125) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated in your comment that every other configuration was identical. So to get the "same" overall exposure to get a consistent brightness within your panorama, you need to adjust your exposure compensation.

The correlation is as follows:
Doubling the exposure means a correction of one f-stop (One Full number in the Lr-Exposure Correction)

An Example:
Image 1 has 1/60s, Image2 has 1/30. 
So to get the same overall brightness in the panorama, you have to push Image1 with +1 or pull Image2 with -1.

The same correction would work if Image1 has 1/100 and Image two has 1/50.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net), and don't worry about it. Hugin, if you use the default nona stitcher, evaluates photometrics of the member images and adjusts automatically for brightness and colors by modeling the camera response curve, exposure, white balance, and vignetting. For examples, see [this article on the Hugin website](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tech/).